# Cannot implicitly convert type object

Tags: c#

I have a following variable (appraisalOption.Contacts) that I’m trying to assign some value as follow on step 2 but I don't believe I have the right syntax, looking for some feedback in the best way to resolve this.

Bellow is some steps on how my object assignment are made:

1.)

```
       var appraisalOption = new AppraisalOptions(AppraisalRequestType.NewOrder) {
            ClientGroup = "1", //options.clientGroup
            };
   
       var appraisalContracts = new AppraisalContact() {
            Borrower = borrower,
            CoBorrower = BuildCoBorrower(fieldValues)};
```

**2.)**

```
    appraisalOption.Contacts = appraisalContracts;
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'EncompassRest.Services.Appraisal.AppraisalContact' to 'EncompassRest.Services.Appraisal.AppraisalContacts'

3.) I'm trying to populate the appraisalOption from Step2 but my step 2 is giving me an error.

```
    var appraisalProduct = new AppraisalProduct(entityRef, appraisalOption) {
            Credentials = credentials,};
```

Note: appraisalOption is of type AppraisalOption as declared as follow bellow:

```
     public sealed class AppraisalOptions : ServiceOptions
       {
          public AppraisalContacts? Contacts { get; set; }
       }


     Public class AppraisalContacts
      {
          public AppraisalContactBorrower? Borrower { get; set; }
      }
```

Contacts is a collection...I'm just stuck in the declaration type.

Comment: `AppraisalContact != appraisalOption.Contacts`, My guess is `Contacts` is some sort of collection.

Comment: Can you show the type of (or definition of) `appraisalOption.Contacts` ?

Comment: It's as the error says, `AppraisalOptions.Contacts` is of type `AppraisalContacts`, but `appraisalContracts` is of type `AppraisalContact` (note the last S).

Comment: So... `appraisalOption.Contacts.Add(appraisalContracts)` though the name `appraisalContracts` seems misleading, since it's an `AppraisalContact`.